# how to use onMenuItemSelected

Tags: android, menuitem

i am using onCreateOptionsItem as shown below in the code, but when i overide onMenuItemSelected, it is marked with red. is there an alternative to it?how
can i fix this errors

**code**:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem miRefrsh = menu.add(0, 1, 0,"refresh");
    miRefrsh.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    //进入关于页面
    MenuItem miScan = menu.add(0, 2, 1, "scan");
    miScan.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
    //退出系统
    MenuItem miCancel = menu.add(0, 3, 2, "cancel");
    miCancel.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    MenuItem miExit = menu.add(0, 4, 2, "exit");
    miExit.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case MEMU_RESCAN: 
            this.mGP.closeConn();
            this.initActivityView(); 
            this.openDiscovery(); 
            return true;
        case MEMU_EXIT: 
            this.finish();
            return true;
        case MEMU_ABOUT: 
            this.openAbout();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
```

Comment: which line it is showing red?

Comment: where is the error ? show the log for error.

Answer (score 5):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  

    // do Your Work Here  
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Android knows about several types of menus (e.g. Options Menu and Context Menu). ''onMenuItemSelected'' is the generic callback. You don't need to use this usually. ''onOptionsItemSelected'' is the callback of the options menu and onContextItemSelected is the callback of the context menu.

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) { //or switch-case
            finish();
        }

        if (id == R.id.your_item1) {

        }

        if (id == R.id.your_item2) {

        } 
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

SUDARSHAN is right. you can use onOptionsItemSelected.

Answer (score 2):

use `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method and extend AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use menuItem.getTitle() and compare to the titles you programmatically added previously. Use menuItem.getId online when you're inflating a XML menu file. Hope this helps